# Taylor Series of cos(x) +1 with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am calculating the approximation of the function `cos(x) + 1` using a Taylor Series Expansion up to order 7 using Tensorflow.

I wrote the following code:

```
x=tf.constant(3.14159,dtype=tf.float32)
result = tf.constant(2,dtype=tf.float32)

    if i % 2 == 1:
        num=tf.math.pow(x, i*2)

        den=math.factorial(i*2)

        result=tf.math.subtract(result,tf.math.divide(num,den))

    else:
        num=tf.math.pow(x, i*2)
        

        den=math.factorial(i*2)

        result=tf.math.add(result,tf.math.divide(num,den))
```

The Taylor Series of the function is

[image]

However, when `x=3.14`, I get conflicting results:

```
MY CODE       ---> -0.21135163
Actual answer ---> 3.52077e-12
```

Can anyone help me point out where am I going wrong?

Comment: I haven't checked your code, but this is likely a math problem. A Taylor series is an expansion around a *point* (here: the origin). For a given number of terms, it is most accurate near that point, and accuracy diminishes the further one gets away from the point. It may even fail to converge when far enough away (see: radius of convergence). In principle you can get more accurate results by using more terms of the expansion (try it), but in finite-precision floating-point arithmetic computation may suffer from accumulation of rounding errors and catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: Yes, sir, you were absolutely right! The code is correct, but this code will return a NaN when the order is more than 77. I mean at this point I am just curious why does it return a NaN

Comment: You might want to print numerator and denominator of each term in the expansion. I suspect they both overflow to infinity (`INF`) at some point, and `INF`/`INF`=`NaN`, since the result of the division is undefined.

Comment: Yes, you are right, can tf.custom_gradient be used to bypass this?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know anything about Tensorflow. Instead of computing the numerator and denominator separately, take the last tern and multiply by x**2 then divide by the next pair of integers. So when the current term is x\*\*2/2!, multiply it by x\*\*2 and divided by (5*6) to get the next term. Rinse and repeat. This way computation shouldn't overflow, but may accumulate more rounding errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Taylor Series diverge very quickly. To get a correct result for your input, you need to use a much higher order.

Here is an example:

```
2 - x**2/2! + x**4/4! - x**6/6!                       ---> -0.2105183783
2 - x**2/2! + x**4/4! - x**6/6! + x**8/8!             --->  0.0238595229
2 - x**2/2! + x**4/4! - x**6/6! + ... - x**10/10!     ---> -0.0018168365
2 - x**2/2! + x**4/4! - x**6/6! + ... + x**12/12!     --->  0.0001010319
2 - x**2/2! + x**4/4! - x**6/6! + ... - x**14/14!     ---> -2.865991e-06
2 - x**2/2! + x**4/4! - x**6/6! + ... + x**16/16!     --->  1.402307e-06
```

Another problem of this method is that it is not very accurate, even with a high order because it have a high condition number and will likely suffer from floating point accumulation issues. Thus, to put it shortly: don't use this method.

You can find more information about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#cos).